# Parse .txt into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists, stringr, quanteda

I have a text file that I want to parse into a dataframe in R.
The text is a collection of poems from the Gutenberg Project (https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1934/pg1934.txt) and I want the information to go into 5 columns:

- book_title
- poem_title
- line_number
- stanza_number
- text

[image: I've included a picture of what the csv should look like]

I have managed to split the text, so I now have several nested lists with information on the stanzas and lines and a few character strings with the poem titles.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 # [1] load the data into the environment
## WITH GUTENBERGR PACKAGE
blake <- gutenberg_download(1934, mirror = "http://mirrors.xmission.com/gutenberg/") %>% 
  select("text")

# [2] turn data into vector ??
blake_v <- as.vector(unlist(blake['text'])) # This gives each line as a string

blake_parse <- parse(text = blake) 

# [3] splitting the text 
books <- str_split(blake_parse,"SONGS OF EXPERIENCE")[[1]] # splitting the text into the two books - 3 chunks: with content, songs of innocence and songs of experience

i <- books[[2]] # Songs of innocence including table of content at the beginning
i <- str_split(i,"SONGS OF INNOCENCE")[[1]] # spliting the table of content from the poems
i <- i[[2]] # Songs of Innocence Poems - just the poems in one string
i <- str_split(i,'\"\", \"\", \"\", \"\",')[[1]] # splitting into the separate poems
e <- books[[3]] # Songs of Experience - just the poems
e <- str_split(e,'\"\", \"\", \"\", \"\",')[[1]] # splitting into the separate poems

i_titles <- str_extract_all(i, "[A-Z]{2,}") # extracting the titles
i_titles <- str_c(i_titles) # combine string elements into one string element
e_titles <- str_extract_all(e, "[A-Z]{2,}") # extracting the titles
e_titles <- str_c(e_titles)

i_poems <- str_remove_all(i, "[A-Z]{2,}") # poem texts without the titles 
e_poems <- str_remove_all(e, "[A-Z]{2,}") # poem texts without the titles 

i_stanza <- str_split(i_poems, '\", \"\", \"') # spliting the text further into stanzas
e_stanza <- str_split(e_poems, '\", \"\", \"') # splitting the text furhter into stanzas

i_lines <- str_split(i_stanza, '\", ')
e_lines <- str_split(e_stanza, '\", ')
```

I think I have all the relevant information, but I don't know how to convert all the information into a dataframe including the numbers of the lines and stanzas.

This is what I did to create a dataframe which includes each line of poem in a row but I don't know how to integrate the other information.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(i_lines), nrow=TRUE, byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df <- pivot_longer(df, 
                   cols = starts_with("x"), 
                   names_to = "text", 
                   values_to = "value")
```

I'm grateful for any tips and recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might be able to simplify this quite a bit given that the text is so structured. What I have done below is take the original tibble created from the `gutenburg_download()` command and then group by book title (the only time that `SONG` starts a line with no white space), then by poem (only lines that start with all-caps), then by stanza (separated by one line of white space).

The `book_titles` and `poem_titles` are vectors containing the values of the book titles and poem titles, respectively, that we use to label factor variables created based on the book and poem numbers.

```r
library(gutenbergr)
library(dplyr)

blake <- gutenberg_download(1934, mirror = "http://mirrors.xmission.com/gutenberg/") %>% 
    select("text")

blake_new <- blake |>
    mutate(
        # Find where each book starts and then create book number based
        # on cumulative sum of how many books have been present
        bookstarts = as.numeric(grepl("^SONGS", text)),
        booknum = cumsum(bookstarts)
    ) %>%
    # Remove front matter & table of contents
    filter(booknum > 0) 

# Gather book titles
book_titles <- blake_new %>% 
    filter(bookstarts != 0) %>%
    pull(text)

blake_new <- blake_new %>%
    mutate(
        # Label factor values then turn into character string based on labels
        book = factor(booknum, labels = book_titles) %>% as.character()
    ) %>%
    # Remove lines containing book titles
    filter(!grepl("(SONGS OF INNOCENCE|SONGS OF EXPERIENCE)", text)) %>%
    mutate(
        # Lagged variable copies data moved down by one row (will be used below
        # to remove repeated blank lines)
        lagged = lag(text),
        # Find where each poem starts based on having two or more capital letters
        poemstarts = as.numeric(grepl("^[A-Z]{2,}", text, perl = TRUE))
    ) %>%
    # Remove rows were both the text and the lagged variables are empty strings
    # (removes repeated blank lines in `text` variable)
    filter(!(text == "" & lagged == "")) %>%
    select(-lagged) %>%
    mutate(
        # Creat poem number based on how many poems have come before
        poemnum = cumsum(poemstarts)
    ) 

# Gather poem titles
poem_titles <- blake_new %>%
    filter(poemstarts > 0) %>%
    pull(text)

blake_new <- blake_new %>%
    mutate(
        # Label poem factor variables and turn into a string variable
        poem = factor(poemnum, labels = poem_titles) %>% as.character()
    ) %>%
    group_by(poem) %>%
    mutate(
        # Find where stanzas start by finding blank lines of text and then 
        # create stanza number within each poem based on number of stanzas that
        # came before
        stanzastarts = as.numeric(grepl("^$", text)),
        stanza_n = cumsum(stanzastarts),
    ) %>%
    # Remove blank lines separating stanzas and poem titles
    filter(!grepl("^$", text) & !(stanza_n == 0)) %>%
    # Create line numbers and zero-index stanza numbers
    mutate(
        line_n = 1:n() - 1,
        stanza_n = stanza_n - 1
        
    ) %>%
    select(book, poem, line_n, stanza_n, text)
```